Why close hypothetical question about possible history of Venus?
IMHO, this question should not be closed:
If ancient Venus really were once habitable, what was its atmospheric composition and average surface temperature?
The question asks for a specific, non-opinion answer. It is asking a hypothetical, which means Astronomy SE won’t take it. It calls for the specialized worldbuilding knowledge that our site has. Yes, it is about real planet of Venus, but we allow tons of hypotheticals about Earth past and future, so why not Venus? If the question had been “I’ve got a fictional world that is Venus-like”, it seems we would have kept it open, which is ridiculous.
Proof that it was a good WB question is in the very good answer posted prior to close.
Please explain why this question should be closed as “not about worldbuilding”.

The Question Has Issues

I read the question over thoroughly. I read the edit logs. I read the comments. I reviewed my perspective regarding Real World Questions.

At first, I was rather confused as to why this question was closed. It clearly IS a worldbuilding question. It should never have been closed for that reason. Currently, I am tempted to VTR on procedural grounds.

However, having reviewed the relevant information, I find that the question, as it is currently written, ought to be closed for a different reason. In other words, it still has unresolved issues that a VTR won't help, so I am inclined to leave it closed. At least until the issues are resolved.

Real World = Not Our Problem. My position has, for a very long time, been that the Real World is simply not our manor. Real world questions are not our domain. Questions like "Caesar crossed the Rubicon in January 49BC. What was Rome like just before this?" is clearly a matter of history. We don't do history here. We don't do exopalaeoclimatology here. We refer such questions to AppropriateStack.SE.

Gratuitous Worldbuilding Context = I was born at night, but not last night. If asking the above question is bad enough, editing your question to say "Caesar crossed the Rubicon in January 49BC. What was Rome like just before this? I'm making a fictional world project and need to know." simply doesn't cut it. This kind of tactic insults our intelligence and, quite frankly, is simply a ploy to get around a rule or policy of this forum.

Lack of WB.SE Research. A cursory glance at questions involving Venus reveals several questions that touch on this topic. I didn't read them in detail, but this question doesn't address them either.

Plenty of external research. The question points out data that support different (and contradictory) theories about ancient Venus. This situation is not addressed in the question at all, so I'm not sure why it was brought up. In other words, if one scientician says NO and the other scientician says YES, the question ought to set the relevant parameters for answering the question taking into account these theories.

This leads us to considering why this question was closed, should remain closed, and if reopened without being edited, why it should be closed again.

A. My speculation is that the close votes were made based on lack of worldbuilding context. We're not introduced to the OP's fictional world at all or given any kind of description of it. It should remain closed based on this observation. If I had participated in the original discussion and vote, I would have VTC for lack of context. I would have also asked the OP to edit it to make it a viable question for WB.SE. And I would also have reminded people not to answer questions that are likely to be closed. Because then we end up in this situation where, once again, we have to address in Meta why a question was closed, and worse, why it can't be fixed.

B. Any question that has Issues should remain closed until its Issues are resolved. This is often not a problem. When issues are caught and questions are closed early, the querent has ample time to clarify and edit the question. However...

C. The question has a Green Checkmark (TM) Accepted Answer. The OP got the desired answer. By admission. The rest of us can just move on. There is no need to reopen this question at this point. Reopening the question as is does not serve the community because of its Issues. Editing the question to make it viable will likely invalidate the answer which is an untenable situation in this community.

While not asked, I'll also address how to avoid this situation in future.

1. First, good answers don't justify bad questions.

2. Querents really do need to learn how to write good WB.SE questions. I say this as someone who has I think asked all of two questions here. And I know neither of them were all that excellent. What I look for as a respondent is a clear sense of worldbuilding context and potential. This question really didn't have either, and I really would recommend the querent give our Sandbox a try. It's here in Meta, and I guarantee that had it been trialled there, its issues would have been discussed and we'd've gotten a really fantastic question out of it!

3. Respondents do need to learn some self control. We all answer poorly worded questions from time to time, myself included. But whenever a question is in the VTC queue, we really do need to pause and pay attention to what the concerns are.

That was a well-written response. It's going to find its way into the Help Center review.

This biggest problem with this is that "Real World = Not Our Problem" only applies to when the real world is a known and proven thing.  The early state of Venus is as shrouded in mystery as the civilization of Atlantis or the fate of Roanoke which are used all throughout literature to add credibility to an otherwise fictional setting because we know that there was something there, but we know so little that there is tons of room fill in the gaps with your own stuff without contradicting any known truths.

As for "Worldbuilding Context" the mysteriousness of ancient Venus, and trying to fill in the gaps enough to create an internally consistent setting requires enough guess work that even if he was asking about the actual historical Venus, the best that exists out there are speculative essays, not actual facts. So this was always an appropriate WorldBuilding question because any conclusions that can be drawn about ancient Venus will by definition be a fictional setting no matter how you try to dress it up.

As for research, the OP did do his job.  He tried to research the topic and found contradicting information that he did not understand.  Because the resources out there were so inconsistent, he needed help to understand the different perspectives. Lastly, accepted answers are not a good reason to leave a question closed, because when you close a question, it impacts its researchability which encourages duplicate questions in the future.

@JBH Please don't this answer is full of problems, and will only lead to more problems.

@Nosajimiki As I mentioned in a comment to your answer, you answered the question that should have been asked, not the question that actually was asked. You appear to be applying Elemtilas' response, above, to the question that should have been asked, not the question that was asked. That's a bad way to approach questions.

The question asked was fine. He changed it to try to make the "Worldbuilding Context" more clear, but it was always an unnecessary change.  My answer could have applied to a speculative version of the real Venus or a Venus like world in another solar system equally, precisely because there is no factual knowledge about Venus's history to begin with.

... the question ought to set the relevant parameters for answering the question taking into account these theories. It did. The question specifically asked about the "yes" outcome.

... several questions that touch on this topic. I didn't read them in detail, but this question doesn't address them either. This doesn't seem like a good argument against. Do users have to address other questions that are similar but don't answer their own Q?

What I can agree on is the lack of worldbuilding context in the question. I think it toed the line between WB and Astronomy, but consider this, this same question asked on SE:Astronomy would likely be closed due to invoking a hypothetical scenario (Venus was habitable in the past, therefore...) I think this distinction puts it under our purview.

@BMF -- 1.  I don't think we necessarily disagree here. It's not a SE rule or a WB.SE policy, but I do find that when querents at least make a mention of other relevant WB.SE queries, they get better answers from us. Even if it's just to say "this doesn't answer my question because of XYZ". Respondents know that we don't have to go down that path. We see this with a lot of potential duplicates. It may not seem like a "good argument", but doing so does remove one potential problem for a question.

@BMF --   2.  I disagree with you on this. I don't see where the querent  set parameters. I see two descriptions of two scientific perspectives (YES & NO); I see a basic assumption about the setting; I see a reiteration of the question.; I see a fake statement of worldbuilding context to get around the forum's policy. But no parameters for anyone to properly answer the question.

@BMF -- 3.  I think the OP would have done a smash-up job if he'd simply described the world he envisions, then brings up the two scientific theories, then lays out what he expects in a good answer then asks the right question: *This is my Venuslike world: does what I have make sense given the likelihoods of option YES and option NO." Or something like that. I don't disagree with you: this question ought to be within our purview, but as written, it is not. It belongs on Astronomy.

@Nosajimiki -- The querent didn't offer any kind of worldbuilding context whatsoever. Hence the question's issue of "real world = not our problem". We refer astronomy questions to the appropriate forum. If the querent had described his world and melded that with a question about real Venus, I'd've been very happy, and would have VTR. After all, Venus is not Earthlike in important ways. I think that had the question been left alone until it could be edited, the OP would have been much better served.

@Nosajimiki -- 1.  Real World = Not Our Problem applies to real world questions such as this one. The ruse of tacking on "oh by the way, I'm building a fictional world" simply does not cut it. The OP gave no context to work with and quite frankly, trying to pull a fast one that way only serves to insult the forum's integrity.  2.  Mysteriousness and filling in gaps. Seriously, I was born at night, but not last night. The problem isn't the mysteriousness of Venus. The problem is that the querent offered ZERO worldbuilding context: he said nothing at all about his own work!

@Nosajimiki -- 3.  Research. I totally agree with you on this one! I actually commented that the querent did "plenty of external research".  He does lack -- or appears to lack -- research on similar questions in WB.SE. I also agree with you that when theories contradict, we can be of great help to worldbuilders in this situation. We can best do that by not answering problematic questions, especially those in the VTC queue. Exercise some restraint and leave the failing question alone until it get edited. This could have been a really good question, and while I think you (cont)

(cont) gave him a good answer, you really didn't do him, or the forum, any great service by answering when you did. Poor timing! The OP now can not edit his question to actually add worldbuilding context or perspective on other related questions, because that might invalidate your answer. He can't ask the same question again, even with context, because then it would be a duplicate. This whole thing is a bad situation that could easily have been avoided!

@elemtilas "I was born at night, but not last night." <- What typically happens in these cases is questions get closed; so, the OP can either change thier question to what they think you want to hear or they can move on, but you can not actually know what thier original intention was because you intuitively know that this behavior is a punishment response.  It is human nature to be less trusting of someone you've punished, so when they change thier question, you perceive deception which frustrates you and encourages further punishment, but you have failed to question why they are bothering to

deceive you to begin with.  If the OP was asking about pure astronomy, then he would have had no motivation to change his question instead of moving on to another more appropriate resource. So, logically speaking, if they have bothered to "deceive" you, knowing the kind of answer they will get from you, then they want a World Building answer, and if there is any level of deceit in how they are asking for it,

it is because they are trying to follow the rules you set.  If you look at this logically and empathetically instead of reactively it's clear that once the nature of the stack is explained, the very act of changing the question is itself World Building intent.

@Nosajimiki -- 1.  Unfortunately, what really ends up happening is someone (and I've done this myself) answers the question before it can be closed and edited. This is problematic because we don't "actually know what the OP's intention is". When questions get answered before they can be edited, we'll never know! We don't actually know what the OP's intention was, because he never told us what his intentions were.

2. Personal attacks are always welcome! They demonstrate the true foundation of argument.

3.  You bring up a valid point about the querent's edit. He asked a real world question, and apparently was called on that so made a (very weak) edit that comes off as "I'm making a fictional world, but I can't really be arsed to focus on that, so just answer the real world question for me." This is not a "deceitful" tactic, as you imply. It's straight up getting around the underlying nature of WB.SE as a forum.

4.  Skirting the basic rules of a forum is not the same thing as "trying to follow the rules". If you read my response, you'll note that I clearly think there was a good question in there. All it needed was to be edited!

@elemtilas But now we've created a paradox.  You know that he had a world building intent now because he edited it, but if the actual planet in his setting was a prehistoric Venus, not a Venus like world, then it was asking him to edit it that actually harmed the question, not my answer.  You say he needed to edit the question, but the question itself was complete enough to be answered as asked within the rules of the stack.  A simple comment asking if this is for a fictional setting or about real life astronomy was all that was needed.

@Nosajimiki Comments are ephemeral. They can and will disappear at a moment's notice. Because comments have no guarantee of sticking around they cannot be relied on to provide clarification. If something is relevant to the question, it should be in the question.

@Nosajimiki -- Indeed! Whether someone says the words "I'm making a fictional world..." or not, I generally presume that's why they're here. (Excepting those who want to ask questions about light sabres and phasers from third party works.) Again, the issue isn't saying the magic words, and it's not presuming that a querent has the intention to make a fictional world. Saying the words only expresses what I'd already presumed! The issue here at least is the edit didn't add new information. It didn't add meaningful context. Yes. He needed to edit the question to provide the (cont)

(cont) worldbuilding context that would make the question appropriate for this forum. And you needed to not answer the question until that context could be added. Right answer, wrong question. The question was complete for Astronomy.SE. Comments is not the appropriate place to address the worldbuilding context.

@elemtilas But the point of not answering is to avoid invalidating future edits.   If I've already established all of the details that I personally find ambiguous in comments, then even if he edits the question later, those edits should be consistent with his comments so they would not invalidate my answer any more than if I got that information from the question itself.

"that I personally find ambiguous" is the key term here.  Other people may have answers in which that detail is completely irrelevant; so, they may not need to wait on clarification.  Pending edits from comments is not a good reason to close a question because not every answer relies on the same details.  In this case, if someone could demonstrate a reason that Early Venus would not be habitable for any form of life, then they would not need any more clarity than the original question provided.  So, you can't hold that person to any reasonable expectation to wait to answer.

@Nosajimiki -- 1.  I agree to an extent! The point of not answering is indeed to avoid invalidating future edits. In this case, the "future edits" would be those that would actually reveal the worldbuilding portion of the question. Comments are meaningless. Any edit the querent might make has only to not invalidate an answer. 2.  This I grant! You may not find a question ambiguous while others might. Of course, ambiguity really isn't this question's problem! As I've said, you wrote a good answer! It's just not an answer to the question that should have been asked. (cont)

(cont) 3. Clarification was never at issue. As you yourself say, the question, even as originally written, "was fine", in that it was clear, made sense, didn't ask multiple questions, etc. The ONLY issue is the lack of worlbuilding context. Put another way, we don't do real world questions!

@elemtilas But is it actually a real world question when the real world does not hold verifiable answers?  I've read plenty of works of fiction about habitable variations of Venus, but the whole planet's crust is less than 500 million years old; so, older stuff is pure guesswork.  Asking what Venus was like back then is like asking about a 150,000 year old language or how iron working could have been discovered.  Just because we know something happened does not mean it exists in the historical record. The shear unknowableness of the question is the WorldBuilding context.

@Nosajimiki A question is about the real word of it is asking about the real word regardless of whether the answer is known to science or not. OP would need to show a willingness to actually build a world and make up facts instead of asking about what happened for the question to be suitable. We are not a site for speculation about what happened in our world. We are a site to help people decide facts about a world that is entirely made up. Unanswerability is a mark against a question being suitable for the Stack Oveflow format, not proof of worldbuilding context.

@sphennings It's not unanswerable because we have things like accretion theory and various rules of chemistry and physics to pull from for making an educated guess, but it ultimately requires making up facts to fill in the blanks about the exact thing the OP asked.  The real world exclusion is just for when there are no facts that need making up like "What is the average surface temperature on Venus?"  As for intent, you already said that you don't know what the OP's original intention was; so, why assume his intent is not worldbuilding when we assume it is for 90% of the questions we answer?

@Nosajimiki -- 1. Absolutely yes! If I ask "what does the Voynich Manuscript say" over on History.SE, it's a totally valid real world question about a real historical artifact. It also happens to be a text with absolutely no viable or verifiable translations as of yet. Just because something involves guesswork does not necessarily involve us. 150,000 year old language: ask on the Linguistics forum. There are actually researchers who try and reconstruct super-ancient languages! Indo-European is probably the most famous, but there is work being done on Nostratic (15k years ago) (cont)

(cont) and as far back as Proto-Sapiens (200k years ago). Simply because something is unknown doesn't make it our province!  2. Even with things like accretion theory and whatever else Science might bring to bear, the ultimate problem with this question is that it has no worldbuilding context. Plain and simple! To go back to the language example, asking how something about Indo-European works is not a right for this forum. Even though we have the linguistics and loads of ancient texts to work from. It's just our business. Give it some worldbuilding context, like you want (cont)

((not our business)) (cont) for the speakers of Indo-European to be teleported to somewhere in MesoAmerica or perhaps North America. A question about how IE speakers' technologies (the wheel, the horse, etc) might affect American civilisations would be more than valid here! The real world exclusion is for all questions about the real world that show no worldbuilding context.

The Question was Edited
The original question was asked much more like he wanted to know about the actual history of the planet. I can see why some users would choose to close it for the same reason we might close a question that asks about the actual history of the Roman Empire; however, when I voted to reopen it after he edited it to fit this stack's criteria, it got voted to stay closed which was completely unfounded as far as I can tell.
And the Original Question Was Fine
That said, I would not have closed the original question myself specifically because there is no consensus about the early state of Venus.  We have no archeological record.  No written accounts. Nothing that constitutes a factual description of the planet; so, anything you might find about it in a textbook is itself nothing more that World Building based educated guess work.

It was fortunate for the OP that you answered the question that should have been asked ("What would be the nature of the atmosphere of a fictional, habitable planet occupying the orbit of Venus?") rather than the question that was asked ("what was the atmosphere of Venus a long time ago assuming hypothesis X is correct?") because what the OP asked was opinion-based. But I don't believe the edits saved the question. There's still too much missing context (inhabitable to what? Why doesn't Earth's atmo answer your question? etc.)

@JHB he clarified in comments "Not necessarily habitable for humans no. Just temperatures sufficient for oceans covering the surface and a thinner atmosphere than modern Venus"

Comments are the worst possible place to address clarifications. Please aggressively remind OPs that they should edit their posts with clarifications, not assume anyone will read comments. At its worst, comment information can become obsolete where the question itself is supposed to represent the most current expression of the question.

@JBH The clarification in comments simply reinforces that he said what he meant and meant what he said.  Habitable just means life can be there.  If he meant habitable by Humans, then yes it would have been necessary to change his question.  Could it be more clear by saying "habitable by native lifeforms"? yes, but holding people to that expectation of clarity would invalidate a lot of the questions on the stack about habitability.  If we want to hold people to this level of clarity, we should update the habitability tag with instructions saying what kind of life is being asked about.

... actually, we SHOULD update that tag for exactly this reason. I do think it's worth expecting people to be clear about, but holding people to expectations that are not accessible and clear is a good way to drive users away.

It's been a while since I read that tag's wiki, so I can't speak to that, but modifying it doesn't magically change how people think. 99% of the time when someone reads the word "habitable," the intrinsic assumption is "habitable for humans." The OP's clarification was necessary because he/she didn't say what he meant and mean what he said. He/she was unclear and the post lacked details. As for accessible and clear, ignoring the current effort to improve the [help], the fact that people don't read the [help] should be their problem, not ours.

@JBH, The Help Center is a bad place to put situational expectations.  The HC is a good place for broad rules that generally don't change like "It has to be clear", but everyone has different default expectations on specific topics; so, it is common for two people to be in disagreement about how clear is clear enough.  Differences of opinion that cite the HC often end in inconclusive debates because the HC by its nature must be vague enough to describe all possible questions which means it can often be interpreted in more than one way.

Tags however set concise and specific expectations, and attach a question directly to those expectations without the OP having to do any deep research to find them.  If the habitability tag says "you must specify the type of life", then there is nothing to argue about. Everyone from the new user to old guy who hasn't re-read the HC recently will see the up-to-date rule right there to be able to say if the OP did thier job or not.

The HC is the only place to put rules that everyone can find and that has authority. I'm speaking from considerable experience trying to develop (and having been periodically successful) Meta-based policies that become lost or forgotten over time, or that are argued as not being authoritative because they're not in the HC. Thus, we'll need to agree to disagree with that assertion. However, You've made a good point about the [tag:habitability] tag (not that anyone reads those, either).

I posted a request for improvement proposals for the [tag:habitability] tag here.
